# Select individual class element

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop

I am trying to have it so that I can create elements with the same class name in HTML, and jQuery will count them, based on order. I have successfully done it before with regular JavaScript, however, I am trying to learn the jQuery API right now. Is there a way I can do it like this? As of now, it is not accepting the $(...)[#] method.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('.description').length; i++) {
    $('.description')[i].before($('<div/>', {
        id: 'q' + (i+1),
        class: 'qNumber',
        text: (i+1) + ')',
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.description').before(function(i) {
    return $('<div/>', {
        id      : 'q' + (i+1),
        'class' : 'qNumber',
        text    : (i+1) + ')',
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksSLB/1/)

Comment: For some reason, I always forget that `before()` can do that...that's far nicer.

Comment: @DavidThomas - So do I, not all the DOM insertion methods takes a function, so I had to test it before answering.

Comment: Thank you so much. One question: is the 'i' parameter in the function standardized as a counter or something? How does it know to get larger by one each time?

Comment: @mvarble - yes, it's a standardized index parameter as jQuery iterates over the collection of elements internally